# Is it possible to install Windows 98 on a VM in order to run a 16 bits app that accesses an old VLB data capture card from the host machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-98, 16-bit

I need to access an old VLB (before PCI controllers) SCADA card with a 16 bits application that controls the data and processes. 
I do have only the DOS driver for that card and I need to install a 32 bits OS on that host machine to allow me remote access (Teamviewer or VNC) to the application from smart devices.
As a solution I was thinking of installing a VM with Windows 98 (where I am sure the application works on the host machine), but I am not sure if the VM may access the VLB controller on the host machine, where the card is installed.
Anyone had any experience with non-standard devices installed on host machine to be accessed by the Virtual Machines running on it? 
What VM solution do you recommend? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think any hypervisor can provide passthrough to such antique hardware. I really hope the purpose of this project is to decommission it.

Comment: Another way could be using a linux live cd with wine (for the app software) and gain access to the SCADA card.

Comment: Windows 98 is _already_ a 32-bit operating system, and there are VNC server versions that will run on it. If you need further compatibility with newer versions of Windows, try using [KernelEx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kernelex/), which will allow you to run a lot of XP-only code.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. You can install and run Windows 98 with old 16 bit apps just fine. The problem is that VM software creates a specific virtual environment, and that simulated computer will not include support for your special capture card. There are some virtual environments that support USB pass-through for VMs, but I'm not aware of any that will do this for PCI (or older) devices.

Comment: PCI most definitely works, if motherboard supports VT-d (I've used PCI network cards and video capture cards in KVM VMs), but VLB is too old for sure.

Comment: The hyervisor knows how to take any network adapter and present it to a VM in a generic way... that's not PCI passthrough. Video capture is nice, though. Which VM product did you use?

Comment: Nope I'm talking about direct PCI path-through, not generic virtualized network card (e.g. I had to install the original hardware's drivers inside the VM). KVM is the platform: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/KVM_PCI_Device_Assignment